# in which vs which

Tags: relative-clauses

> Avatar is set in an Asiatic-inspired world **in** which some people
> can telekinetically manipulate one of the four elements

i saw this sentence on wikipedia.

does it necessary to put an **in** before **which**? I basically can not understand the necessity of **in**. Is it possible to write it without **in**? to me its much more clear in that way.

Comment: "_Avatar_ is set in an Asiatic-inspired world. **In** that world, some people can..."

Answer (score 2):

If you rearrange the sentence to get rid of the relative clause, you get:

> Some people can telekinetically manipulate one of the four elements **in** the Asiatic-inspired world of *Avatar*.

Since you need **in** in this rearranged sentence, you need to say **in which**; just dropping the **in** would be ungrammatical.

However, your instinct is correct ... getting rid of the **in** is a good idea, and you can do this by using **where** instead of **in which**:

> *Avatar* is set in an Asiatic-inspired world **where** some people can manipulate one of the four elements.

This sentence is clearer than the original.

Comment: If you want to drop **in** and keep **which** you need to add a verb which has *which* (meaning *world*) as its subject. This would require other changes as well. For example "*Avatar* is set in an Asiatic-inspired world which **has** some people **who** can manipulate one of the four elements". Whatever you write after *which* has to be able to follow *The Avatar world* - like "The *Avatar* world has some people who can manipulate one of the four elements".